# ROS cannot install Noetic due to unmet dependencies 20.04

Tags: ros, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Today I've tried installing ROS Noetic on a fresh install on 20.04 Ubuntu. Following the instructions on the ROS wiki for installation. I've now tried this both in a VM on a desktop, and without a VM on a laptop. Both with fresh installs on 20.04 LTS. In both setups I am met with the error:

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-noetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-noetic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-noetic-urdf-sim-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anyone know how to correct this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377877/ros-cannot-install-noetic-due-to-unmet-dependencies-20.04/) by [vchalk](https://answers.ros.org/users/73907/vchalk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-05-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-05-06**:
Check out [#q279780](https://answers.ros.org/question/279780/unmet-dependencies-for-ros-desktop-full/), [#q282399](https://answers.ros.org/question/282399/sudo-apt-get-install-ros-indigo-desktop-full-e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages/), [#q315820](https://answers.ros.org/question/315820/melodic-fresh-install-unmet-dependencies/), [#q243920](https://answers.ros.org/question/243920/how-to-install-ros-kinetic-ubuntu-1604/). Using `aptitude` in place of `apt` might be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's likely you are running into [osrf/gazebo#2995](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/2995).

The Pull Request fixing that is already merged: [ros-infrastructure/reprepro-updater#114](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/reprepro-updater/pull/114).

It will take some time for fixes to propagate to the main repositories however.

If you must absolutely install Noetic right now, you could try adding the [Gazebo package repositories](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu), which should have the needed package(s).

Note: you should **only need to add the repository**. You do not need to install Gazebo separately.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [totosolat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12266/totosolat/) on 2021-05-07**:
Thanks, adding the Gazebo package repositories worked for me following this process:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'

wget https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

dont forget to update sources:

```
sudo apt update
```

then you sould be able to install ros following these [instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-07**:
Note: this is just a **work-around** until the problematic packages have been added to the ROS repositories.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be an out dated dependencies for the ignition physics library. I resolved the issue by doing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lsb-release

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'

wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

and then use aptitude, it resolved the problem

The above install instruction is basically from https://ignitionrobotics.org/api/physics/1.2/installation.html

---

Originally posted by [frank-qcd-qk](https://answers.ros.org/users/74218/frank-qcd-qk/) with karma: 11 on 2021-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

Hello，I'm having the same problem.

My environment is as follows:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- ROS noetic

When I run the command like this, I get the same error:

[image]

My solution is:

[image]

1. open the `Software & Updates`
2. click the `Updates`
3. change the contents of the red box to `All updates` or `Security and recommended updates`
4. click the `close` and `reload`

Then, I can run the command successfully.

I hope what I've said is helpful!